# How to store an received data in an variable jquery

Tags: jquery

How to store the received the data from an remote php file in an variable using jquery.
I receive the data using

```
 $.post("test.php", {query: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
                alert(data);
            });
        }
```

It works i can receive the data inside the function(data) but can i sore the data in an variable and use it in another function some thing like

```
 var data =  $.post("test.php", {query: ""+inputString+""});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery ajax function works but can't return the variable correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101991/jquery-ajax-function-works-but-cant-return-the-variable-correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that because AJAX is asynchronous, meaning that the result is only available inside the success callback which might run much later than the actual `$.post` call. So instead of trying to store the result into a variable, use the success callback which is the only reliable place to consume the results of an AJAX request to call some other method for example and do some processing on those results:

```
$.post("test.php", { query: inputString }, function(data) {
    someFunction(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myResult;
$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
      myResult=data;
      $(body).trigger('myAjaxComplete')
});
```

But the problem with that is, that AJAX is asynchronous, so you never know WHEN the AJAX is completely done. You could trigger a custom Event like above and listen for it. So you would know the ajax has completed and you have the data for sure:

```
$(body).on('myAjaxComplete',function(){
      //do whatever you like to do with your data
});
```

Or another way would be calling a function with your data:

```
$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
        myAjaxisDoneSoContinue(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the another function use the `data` in the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

just set it to a variable.

```
var storedData;
$.post("test.php", {query: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
                storedData = data;
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the variable outside of the function

```
var backData = '';
$.post("test.php", {query: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
    alert(data);
    backData = data;
});
```

Then you can use backData in other functions

Comment: Unfortunately you never know when this `backData` variable will be assigned a value in order to use it. The only reliable place is inside the success callback.

Comment: you can use a synchronized ajax post provided by JQuery by setting  `async: false`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `function (data)` is a `callback` which is called on an event (when the data is being revieved). You see, javascript is asynchronous language, which means that some functions are called not one by one, but on some events. You should use your data inside the callback funciton, and put all the logic, which depends on it, inside the callback

```
$.post("test.php", {query: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
            // manipulate date, call another functions, etc;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

create a global variable in which you store the data you receive, in your case outside the post construction

for larger projects it might be useful to create a separate script for every variable or constant, this script should be included at the same level with your other scripts. this way you have all your variables already defined when you need to work with them

Same thing can be done for constants to have them all in one place and not browse trough the project to find them